# Generate Derived Key from Shared Secret (ECDH-ES) - ConcatKDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, diffie-hellman, kdf

I have used the https://github.com/ricmoo/GMEllipticCurveCrypto to generate a Shared Secret using ECDH Algorithm.

I now have to Generate a Derived Key using the ECDH-ES algorithm as mentioned here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-4.6

I had highly appreciate if someone could guide me in the direction of generating a Derived Key

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) in general and [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) as common example. BTW KDF was mentioned in link you provided.